Form of joint distribution of Markov model
Consider a time series model:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec x_t &= \mathbf A \vec x_{t-1} + \vec w,\ \text{where we have i.i.d.}\ \vec w \sim N(\vec 0, \mathbf Q) \\
\vec x_0 &\sim N(\vec \mu_0, \mathbf \Sigma_0)
\end{align}
$$
$\mathbf A$ represents a constant linear transform.
What is the form of the joint distribution $p(\vec x_T, \dots, \vec x_0)$?
A solution mentioned that the set of multivariate gaussians is closed under linear transforms and additions, thus all $\vec x_i$ are gaussians - which I understand. Then it claims that thus they are also jointly multivariate gaussian. However, I don't see the link in this last step.
My reasoning is that if we decompose the joint density, we get:
$$
p(\vec x_T, \dots, \vec x_0) = p(\vec x_0) \prod_{t=1}^T p(\vec x_t \mid \vec x_{t-1})
$$
since the model is a Markov chain, and each conditional density is itself normally distributed as $N(\mathbf A \vec x_{t-1}, \mathbf Q)$. There is also no evidence here that the product of these normal pdfs will product a normal pdf for the joint distribution.
Thanks for you time!

$\def\iddots{\kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.}}\\
\def\A{\mathbf{A}}\\
\def\x{\vec{x}}\\
\def\w{\vec{w}}\\
\def\Q{\mathbf{Q}}\\
\def\0{\vec{0}}\\
\def\I{\mathbf{I}}\\
\def\b{\mathbf{0}}$
For every $\ t\ $ you have
$$
\x_t=\A\x_{t-1}+\w_t\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
where you have specified that $\ \w_1,\w_2,\dots,\w_T\ $ are independent multivariate normal and $\ \x_0\ $ is multivariate normal. By repeated back substitution in (\ref{e1}) you get
$$
\x_t=\A^t\x_0+\sum_{i=1}^t\A^{t-i}\w_i
$$
for every $\ t\ $, or
$$
\pmatrix{\x_T\\\x_{T-1}\\\vdots\\\x_0}=\pmatrix{\A^T&\A^{T-1}&\dots&\A&\I\\
\A^{T-1}&\A^{T-2}&\dots&\I&\b\\
\A^{T-2}&\A^{T-3}&\dots&
\b&\b\\
\vdots&\vdots&\iddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\I&\b&\dots&\b&\b}\pmatrix{\x_0\\\w_1\\\vdots\\\w_T}\ .
$$
Thus, assuming $\ \x_0\ $ is independent of $\ \w_1,\w_2,\dots,\w_T\ $ (which you haven't explicitly specified), $\ \pmatrix{\x_0&\w_1&\dots&\w_T}\ $ will follow a multivariate normal distribution with mean $\ \pmatrix{\vec{\mu}_0&\0&\dots&\0}\ $ and covariance matrix
$$
\pmatrix{\mathbf{\Sigma}_0&\b&\b&\dots&\b\\
\b&\Q&\b&\dots&\b\\
\b&\b&\Q&\dots&\b\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
\b&\b&\b&\dots&\Q}\ .
$$
Since  $\ \pmatrix{\x_T&\x_{T-1}&\dots&\x_0}\ $ is a linear function of $\ \pmatrix{\x_0&\w_1&\dots&\w_T}\ $ it must also follow a multivariate normal distribution.

Thanks for the detailed answer! I could follow the argument but there's a gap in my understanding of it: how did you conclude that $\left(\vec x_0 \vec w_1 \dots \vec w_T \right)$ will follow a multivariate normal distribution? Is it because any set of independently (multi)variate normal distributions are also automatically joint normal?

Yes. When, they're independent the density function of the lot of them is just the product $$\ Ke^{-\frac{1}{2}\left((\vec{x}_0-\vec{\mu}_0)^T\mathbf{\Sigma}_0^{-1}(\vec{x}_0-\vec{\mu}0)+\sum\limits{i=1}^T\vec{w}^T\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\vec{w}\right)}\ ,$$of their individual density functions.  The resulting product is just the density function of the multivariate normal distribution with the mean and covariance matrix I gave in my answer.

I see. Then would it also make sense to directly go from the later part of my original question as:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\vec x_0, \dots, \vec x_T) &= p(\vec x_0) \prod_{t=1}^T p(\vec x_t \mid \vec x_{t-1}) \
&= C e^{-\frac12 \left( \left( \vec x_0 - \vec \mu_0 \right)^\intercal \Sigma_0^\intercal \left( \vec x_0 - \vec \mu_0 \right) + \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\vec x_t - A \vec x_{t-1} \right)^\intercal Q^{-1} \left(\vec x_t - A \vec x_{t-1} \right) \right)}
\end{align}
$$
which would have a similar form to your expression above and is thus gaussian?

Yes, that should give you the same expression for the density.
